# MVC Razor RenderPartial Call Not Working in Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, renderpartial

I am trying to include some reusable code throughout my website (not web application) via the RenderPartial call @Html.RenderPartial("SomePage.cshtml").  In asp I was just able to use #include virtual="somefile.asp".  However, I receive the following error message.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'RenderPartial' and no extension
>   method 'RenderPartial' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have include all the appropriate references in my web.config file.

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>       
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Is the RenderPartial only available in "Web Applications" and not "Websites"?
Is there a better way to reuse code throughout the site?
@RenderSection does not work in my situation since the layout I'm using does not reuse the code in the same location.

Comment: Is that `Web.config` the one located in the `Views` directory?

Comment: Note that MVC officially only supports the Web Application project model.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by using @RenderPage("SomePage.html").  Only took 2 days to find the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `<add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>` under the namespace section?